# Whitespace showing up at bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css, menu, whitespace

I am running into an issue with some white space at the bottom of my page that came out of no where.

I added a slide out menu to my desktop and this is when the white space started showing. It has been showing in my mobile media query for quite some time (this always had the slide-out menu), so I have got the issue nailed down to something in the slide-out menu. However, looking at the dev tools, I can't definitely figure out which part of my nav-menu that causes the whitespace. Hee is an image that shows which elements show up in that area, but in my code I do not see anything that causes it.

[image]

I believe this is the relevant code.

```css
    .nav-panel-content {

      position: absolute;

      top: 0;

      left: 0;

      width: 100%;

      height: 100%;

      padding: 50px 0 0 0;

      overflow: hidden;

      /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */

      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    }

    .from-right .nav-panel-container {

      right: 0;

      -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);

      -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);

      -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);

      -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);

      transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);

    }

    .nav-panel-container {

      position: fixed;

      width: 50%;

      height: 100%;

      top: 0;

      bottom: 0;

      background: #F0F0F0;

      z-index: 1;

      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;

      -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;

      transition-property: transform;

      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;

      -moz-transition-duration: 0.7s;

      transition-duration: 0.7s;

      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;

      -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;

      transition-delay: 0.3s;

    }

    .nav-panel::after {

      /* overlay layer */

      position: absolute;

      top: 0;

      left: 0;

      width: 100%;

      height: 100%;

      background: transparent;

      -webkit-transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;

      -moz-transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;

      transition: background 0.8s 0.8s;

    }

    .nav-panel {

      position: fixed;

      top: 0;

      left: 0;

      height: 100%;

      width: 100%;

      visibility: hidden;

      -webkit-transition: visibility 1s;

      -moz-transition: visibility 1s;

      transition: visibility 1s;

      z-index: 999999999999;

    }

    .nav-panel-list {

      display: block;

      background-color: #F0F0F0;

      margin: 0;

      list-style: none;

      text-align: right;

      width: 100%;

      padding: 0;

      z-index: 9999999;

    }
```

```html
<div class="nav-panel from-right">
  <header class="nav-panel-header">
    <div id="nav-slide-title">Menu</div>
    <a href="#0" class="nav-panel-close">Close</a>
  </header>
  <div class="nav-panel-container">
    <div class="nav-panel-content">
      <ul class="nav-panel-list">
        <a href="test_index">
          <li>HOME</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>WORK</li>
        </a>
        <a href="approach">
          <li>APPROACH</li>
        </a>
        <a href="services">
          <li>SERVICES</li>
        </a>
        <a href="contact">
          <li>CONTACT</li>
        </a>
        <span id="nav-project"><a href="discuss-project"><li>DISCUSS A PROJECT</li></a></span>
      </ul>
      <div id="nav-social-container">
        <div id="nav-social-title">DON'T BE SHY, LET'S GET SOCIAL.</div>
        <div id="nav-social-icons"><span class="nav-social-icon"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="/icons/facebookBlack.png" alt="facebook" height="30px" width="30px"></a></span><span class="nav-social-icon"><a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="/icons/twitterBlack.png" alt="twitter" height="30px" width="30px"></a></span>
          <span
          class="nav-social-icon">
            <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank">
              <img src="/icons/linkedInBlack.png" alt="linkedIn" height="30px" width="30px">
            </a>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- nav-panel-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- nav-panel-container -->
</div>
<!-- nav-panel -->
```

Comment: Disappears if I remove the padding: `#dark-gray-container {
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 150px 0; */
}`

Comment: The reason I said it is not worth an answer:  there is a comment that solves the issue and this question is very specific for your website only.

Comment: Why, I have come across website related issues that helped me before. Thanks for helping. I do appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That white space is caused by padding. Go to your main-style.css and remove the following.

```
#dark-gray-container-button {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

And change the padding for this one

```
#dark-gray-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 150px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: beat you to it! Not really worth an answer

Comment: @mplungjan Your comment isn't really worth anything. Nor does it add any value to this question.  Thanks Divakar!

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by:

```
*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: This took that white-space away, but not my X does not show up in the nav-menu. How could I still get the X to show up and get this whitespace to now show?

Comment: Thanks for the help, though!